# Msi ProgressText failed to display the parameters correctly

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a msi installation package made by WIX.
In a particular case, the text above the progress bar is not displayed correctly.

Windows system: **Windows10 enterprise (64bit)**

Version of msiexec: **Windows Installer. V 5.0.15063.0.**

[image]

Is it my WIX that needs to be set up for compatibility Settings, or is there a problem with msiexec itself?

Comment: Did you de-compile a non-WiX MSI (for example created with Installshield) and then recompile it with WiX?

Answer (score 0):

These come from the ProgressText elements in the WiX source, which go into the ActionText table of an MSI file. There's a general standard list here:

http://web.mit.edu/ops/services/afs/openafs-1.4.1/src/src/WINNT/install/wix/lang/en_US/ActionText.wxi

Note that they have a standard template for parameters.

I thought some of the WiX UI choices would include this automatically, if so that might be an easier choice.